# Problemas com relacionamento Entity Framework Core 3,

Tags: .net, console, entity-framework-core, dotnet-cli

Vou expor o código primeiro, depois explico o problema.

Aluno.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SalaDeAula.Models
{
    public class Aluno
    {
        public int AlunoId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Turma Turma { get; set; }
        public List<Nota> Notas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Disciplina.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SalaDeAula.Models
{
    public class Disciplina 
    {
        public int DisciplinaId { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
        public Grade Grade { get; set; }
        public List<Nota> Nota { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Grade.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SalaDeAula.Models
{
    public class Grade
    {
        public int GradeId { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public List<Disciplina> Disciplinas { get; set; }
        public List<Turma> Turma { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Notas.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SalaDeAula.Models
{
    public class Nota
    {
        public int NotaId { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public float nota { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AlunoId")]
        [InverseProperty("Notas")]
        public Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
        public Disciplina Disciplina { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Turma.cs

```
namespace SalaDeAula.Models
{
    public class Turma
    {
        public int TurmaId { get; set; }
        public string Serie { get; set; }
        public Grade Grade { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Contexto.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SalaDeAula.Models
{
    public class Contexto : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Disciplina> Disciplinas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Turma> Turmas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Nota> Notas { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Database=EFcore.Escola;User Id=sa;Password=MyPassWord");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            #region Disciplina
                modelBuilder.Entity<Disciplina>().HasKey(p => p.DisciplinaId);
            #endregion
            #region Grade
                modelBuilder.Entity<Grade>().HasKey(p => p.GradeId);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Grade>().HasMany(p => p.Disciplinas);
            #endregion

            #region Turma
                modelBuilder.Entity<Turma>().HasKey(p => p.TurmaId);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Turma>().HasOne(p => p.Grade);
            #endregion

            #region Aluno
                modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>().HasKey(p => p.AlunoId);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>().HasOne(p => p.Turma);
            #endregion
        
            #region Nota
                modelBuilder.Entity<Nota>().HasKey(p => p.NotaId);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Nota>().HasOne(p => p.Aluno);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Nota>()
                    .HasOne(p => p.Disciplina)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Nota)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SalaDeAula.Models;

namespace SalaDeAula
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(var db = new Contexto())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                /*db.Disciplinas.Add(new Disciplina
                    {nome="Matemática", descricao="Matéria dos números."}
                );
                db.Disciplinas.Add(new Disciplina
                    {nome="Portuguẽs", descricao="Matéria das letras."}
                );
                db.Disciplinas.Add(new Disciplina
                    {nome="Geografia", descricao="Matéria dos paises."}
                );
                db.SaveChanges();

                List<Disciplina> disciplinas = new List<Disciplina>();
                foreach(var d in db.Disciplinas){
                    disciplinas.Add(d);
                }

                db.Grades.Add(new Grade{
                    Descricao="Matérias do 3º ano",
                    Disciplinas=disciplinas
                });
                db.SaveChanges();

                List<Grade> grades = new List<Grade>();
                foreach(var d in db.Grades){
                    grades.Add(d);
                }

                db.Turmas.Add(new Turma {
                    Grade=grades[0],
                    Serie="3-A",
                });

                db.SaveChanges();

                db.Alunos.Add(new Aluno {
                    Email="afonso@afonso.com",
                    Nome="Afonso Medeiros",
                    Turma=db.Turmas.First()
                });
                db.SaveChanges();*/
                

                db.Notas.Add(new Nota {
                    Aluno=db.Alunos.Single(a=>a.AlunoId==1),
                    Descricao="prova de matemática",
                    Disciplina=db.Disciplinas.Single(d=>d.DisciplinaId==1),
                    nota= 9.6F
                });
                db.Notas.Add(new Nota {
                    Aluno=db.Alunos.Single(a=>a.AlunoId==1),
                    Descricao="prova de Portuques",
                    Disciplina=db.Disciplinas.Single(d=>d.DisciplinaId==2),
                    nota= 6.2F
                });
                db.Notas.Add(new Nota {
                    Aluno=db.Alunos.Single(a=>a.AlunoId==1),
                    Descricao="prova de Geografia",
                    Disciplina=db.Disciplinas.Single(d=>d.DisciplinaId==3),
                    nota= 7.0F
                });
                db.SaveChanges();

                foreach (var i in db.Notas.ToList())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Aluno {i.Aluno.Nome} | Turma {i.Aluno.Turma.Serie} | Disciplina: {i.Disciplina} | Nota {i.nota}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Shell:

```
dotnet ef migrations "inicial"
dotnet ef database update
dotnet build
dotnet run
```

Erro:

```
Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SalaDeAula.Program.Main(String[] args) in home/afonso/Documentos/projetos/C#/BrincandoEF/SalaDeAula/Program.cs:line 80
```

Bem... a parte do código do arquivo Program.cs que está comentada funciona e é consultada e tá uma maravilha, mas a parte descomentada também "funciona" mas na classe Nota depois que eu tento consultar depois de realizar o saveChanges ele retorna "Aluno" como null... Alguém saberia como posso resolver, tentei seguir tanto a doc do EF Core, mas talvez eu tenha deixado algo passar.

Comment: Na base de dados as notas estão com o id do aluno, certo?

Comment: simm estão sim!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar queries mais lentas desnecessárias, apesar das propriedades que se encontram em outras tabelas existirem no seu modelo, o Entity Framework não trará os seus valores automaticamente.

Para resolver este seu caso específico, podem ser usados os métodos `Include` e `ThenInclude`:

```cs
var notas = db.Notas
  .Include(notas => notas.Aluno)
    .ThenInclude(aluno => aluno.Turma)
  .ToList();

foreach (var i in notas)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Aluno {i.Aluno.Nome} | Turma {i.Aluno.Turma.Serie} | Disciplina: {i.Disciplina} | Nota {i.nota}");
}
```

---

Existem 3 formas diferentes de se trabalhar com o Entity Framework:

- **Eager loading**: os dados são carregados na query inicial.
- **Lazy loading**: os dados são carregados quando necessário.
- **Explicit loading**: os dados serão explicitamente carregados posteriormente.

### 1. Eager loading

Quando se sabe ao certo todos os dados que serão necessários, pode-se usar o **Eager loading**, conforme apresentado anteriormene nesta resposta (com o uso do `Include`).

### 2. Lazy loading

Em algumas situações pode ser prático usar o **Lazy loading**. Neste caso é recomendado o uso do package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`. Além disso, será necessário garantir que as propriedades que se pretende que seja usado o **Lazy loading** sejam `virtual` e alterar a configuração do seu DB Context.

```cs
public class Nota
{
  (...)
  public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
}

public class Aluno
{
  (...)
  public virtual Turma Turma { get; set; }
}

// setup do db context
.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(b =>
  b.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
   .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

### 3. Explicit loading

Para usar o **Explicit loading** é preciso carregar os dados quando se pretender fazer o uso deles utilizando o método `Load`.

```cs
var notas = db.Notas;
(...)
db.Entry(notas)
  .Collection(nota => nota.Aluno)
  .Load();
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou, mas ainda fiquei com duas dúvidas, a primeira: O que é o modificador Virtual? no que exatamente ele transforma o atributo? e na tentativa de resolver meu problema eu tentei utilizar DataAnnotations, é bom usar data annotations ou devo utilizar a configuração no contexto mesmo? ou é uma questão de conforto?